# What's correct solution for SOAP fault WSDL error?

Tags: php, magento, soap, wsdl

I got this error when i am trying to connect with magento v2.0.2 SOAP API.

I am running on localhost

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://127.0.0.1/cms_framework/Magento-CE-2.0.2/soap?wsdl' : 
failed to load external entity "http://127.0.0.1/cms_framework/Magento-CE-2.0.2/soap?wsdl" in /var/www/html/upwork/ci_api_work/api/application/libraries/magentoapi.php:37 Stack trace: 
#0 /var/www/html/upwork/ci_api_work/api/application/libraries/magentoapi.php(37): SoapClient->SoapClient('http://127.0.0....') 
#1 /var/www/html/upwork/ci_api_work/api/system/core/Loader.php(1011): magentoapi->__construct() 
#2 /var/www/html/upwork/ci_api_work/api/system/core/Loader.php(888): CI_Loader->_ci_init_class('magentoapi', '', NULL, NULL) 
#3 /var/www/html/upwork/ci_api_work/api/system/core/Loader.php(138): CI_Loader->_ci_load_class('magentoapi', NULL, NULL) 
#4 /var/www/html/upwork/ci_api_work/api/application/controllers/magento.php(11): CI_Loader->library('magentoapi') 
#5 /var/www/html/upwork/ci_api_work/api/application/controllers/magento.php(23): magento->connect() 
#6 [internal in /var/www/html/upwork/ci_api_work/api/application/libraries/magentoapi.php on line 37
```

I tried most of the solutions and none of them working.

1. SOAP installed
2. ssl present in php.ini file
3. on file get contents return nothing

Comment: I'd start by loading `http://127.0.0.1/cms_framework/Magento-CE-2.0.2/soap?wsdl` in a browser.  You should see an XML file? What do you see?  Is it different id you load it directly from the server Magento's running on?

Comment: i am getting xml on browser, but from my PHP script can't access this instead of getting error.

Answer (score 0):

This helped to me:

```
$opts = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
);

$options = array (
    'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
    'verifypeer' => false,
    'verifyhost' => false,
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
    'trace' => 1,
    'exceptions' => 1,
    'connection_timeout' => 180,
    'stream_context' => stream_context_create($opts),
    'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
    //'compression' => SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT | SOAP_COMPRESSION_GZIP | 1
);

$client = new SoapClient($yourServer, $options);
```